# How to get clangd completer working with Unrealengine-4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, clangd

So i have been trying to learn unrealengine4 and wanted to use vim as my editor.
As an autocompletion engine i wanted to use CoC with clangd.
After some fiddling around to get my compile_commands.json almost everything works as expected.
But i get the following two errors in every document i open.
(Just for clarification, when i use VSCode i also get the same errors if i use the clangd completion engine)

1. `In included file: Exactly one of [UE_BUILD_DEBUG UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT UE_BUILD_TEST UE_BUILD_SHIPPING] should be defined to be 1[clang: pp_hash_error]`
2. `Incomplete type 'UOpenDoor' named in nested name specifier[clang: incomplete_nested_name_spec]` ( assuming i open a module named OpenDoor.cpp)

The first error i was able to trace back to the Unrealengine Build Tool, as the file that contains the definition of this error is located in `UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/Build.h`

The file is as follows:

```
#pragma once


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Build configuration coming from UBT, do not modify
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Set any configuration not defined by UBT to zero
#ifndef UE_BUILD_DEBUG
    #define UE_BUILD_DEBUG              0
#endif
#ifndef UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
    #define UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT        0
#endif
#ifndef UE_BUILD_TEST
    #define UE_BUILD_TEST               0
#endif
#ifndef UE_BUILD_SHIPPING
    #define UE_BUILD_SHIPPING           0
#endif
#ifndef UE_GAME
    #define UE_GAME                     0
#endif
#ifndef UE_EDITOR
    #define UE_EDITOR                   0
#endif
#ifndef UE_BUILD_SHIPPING_WITH_EDITOR
    #define UE_BUILD_SHIPPING_WITH_EDITOR 0
#endif
#ifndef UE_BUILD_DOCS
    #define UE_BUILD_DOCS               0
#endif

/** 
 *   Whether compiling for dedicated server or not.
 */
#ifndef UE_SERVER
    #define UE_SERVER                   0
#endif

// Ensure that we have one, and only one build config coming from UBT
#if UE_BUILD_DEBUG + UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT + UE_BUILD_TEST + UE_BUILD_SHIPPING != 1
    #error Exactly one of [UE_BUILD_DEBUG UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT UE_BUILD_TEST UE_BUILD_SHIPPING] should be defined to be 1
#endif


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Legacy defined we want to make sure don't compile if they came in a merge.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FINAL_RELEASE_DEBUGCONSOLE  (#)
#define FINAL_RELEASE               (#)
#define SHIPPING_PC_GAME            (#)
#define UE_BUILD_FINAL_RELEASE (#)

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mandatory bridge options coming from UBT, do not modify directly!
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 * Whether we are compiling with the editor; must be defined by UBT
 */
#ifndef WITH_EDITOR
    #define WITH_EDITOR 0 // for auto-complete
    #error UBT should always define WITH_EDITOR to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
 * Whether we are compiling with the engine; must be defined by UBT
 */
#ifndef WITH_ENGINE
    #define WITH_ENGINE 0 // for auto-complete
    #error UBT should always define WITH_ENGINE to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
 *  Whether we are compiling with developer tools; must be defined by UBT
 */
#ifndef WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS
    #define WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS     0   // for auto-complete
    #error UBT should always define WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
 *  Whether we are compiling with plugin support; must be defined by UBT
 */
#ifndef WITH_PLUGIN_SUPPORT
    #define WITH_PLUGIN_SUPPORT     0   // for auto-complete
    #error UBT should always define WITH_PLUGIN_SUPPORT to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
 * Whether we are compiling with Slate accessibility and automation support
 */
#ifndef WITH_ACCESSIBILITY
    #define WITH_ACCESSIBILITY      1
#endif

 /** Enable perf counters */
#ifndef WITH_PERFCOUNTERS
    #define WITH_PERFCOUNTERS       0
#endif

/** 
 * Whether we are compiling a PGO instrumented build.
 */
#ifndef ENABLE_PGO_PROFILE
    #define ENABLE_PGO_PROFILE 0
#endif

/**
 * Unreal Header Tool requires extra data stored in the structure of a few core files. This enables some ifdef hacks to make this work. 
 * Set via UBT, do not modify directly
 */
#ifndef HACK_HEADER_GENERATOR
    #define HACK_HEADER_GENERATOR 0
#endif

/** Whether we are compiling with automation worker functionality.  Note that automation worker defaults to enabled in
    UE_BUILD_TEST configuration, so that it can be used for performance testing on devices */
#ifndef WITH_AUTOMATION_WORKER
    #define WITH_AUTOMATION_WORKER !(UE_BUILD_SHIPPING || HACK_HEADER_GENERATOR)
#endif

/**
* Whether we want a monolithic build (no DLLs); must be defined by UBT
*/
#ifndef IS_MONOLITHIC
    #define IS_MONOLITHIC 0 // for auto-complete
    #error UBT should always define IS_MONOLITHIC to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
* Whether we want a program (shadercompilerworker, fileserver) or a game; must be defined by UBT
*/
#ifndef IS_PROGRAM
    #define IS_PROGRAM 0 // for autocomplete
    #error UBT should always define IS_PROGRAM to be 0 or 1
#endif

/**
* Whether we support hot-reload. Currently requires a non-monolithic build and non-shipping configuration.
*/
#ifndef WITH_HOT_RELOAD
    #define WITH_HOT_RELOAD (!IS_MONOLITHIC && !UE_BUILD_SHIPPING && !UE_BUILD_TEST && !UE_GAME && !UE_SERVER)
#endif

/**
* Whether we include support for text archive formats. Disabling support allows de-virtualizing archive calls
* and eliminating string constants for field names.
*/
#ifndef WITH_TEXT_ARCHIVE_SUPPORT
    #define WITH_TEXT_ARCHIVE_SUPPORT WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA
#endif

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Optional bridge options coming from UBT, do not modify directly!
    If UBT doesn't set the value, it is assumed to be 0, and we set that here.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 * Checks to see if pure virtual has actually been implemented, this is normally run as a CIS process and is set (indirectly) by UBT
 *
 * @see Core.h
 * @see ObjectMacros.h
 **/
#ifndef CHECK_PUREVIRTUALS
    #define CHECK_PUREVIRTUALS 0
#endif

/** Whether to use the null RHI. */
#ifndef USE_NULL_RHI
    #define USE_NULL_RHI 0
#endif

/** If not specified, disable logging in shipping */
#ifndef USE_LOGGING_IN_SHIPPING
    #define USE_LOGGING_IN_SHIPPING 0
#endif

#ifndef USE_CHECKS_IN_SHIPPING
    #define USE_CHECKS_IN_SHIPPING 0
#endif

/** If not defined follow the CHECK behavior since previously ensures were compiled in with checks */
#ifndef USE_ENSURES_IN_SHIPPING
    #define USE_ENSURES_IN_SHIPPING USE_CHECKS_IN_SHIPPING
#endif

#ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE_IN_SHIPPING
    #define ALLOW_CONSOLE_IN_SHIPPING 0
#endif

/** Compile flag to force stats to be compiled */
#ifndef FORCE_USE_STATS
    #define FORCE_USE_STATS 0
#endif

/**
 *  Optionally enable support for named events from the stat macros without the stat system overhead
 *  This will attempt to disable regular stats system and use named events instead
 */
#ifndef ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS
    #define ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS  0
#endif

#ifndef ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS_UOBJECT
    #define ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS_UOBJECT 0
#endif

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Basic options that by default depend on the build configuration and platform

    DO_GUARD_SLOW                                   If true, then checkSlow, checkfSlow and verifySlow are compiled into the executable.
    DO_CHECK                                        If true, then checkCode, checkf, verify, check, checkNoEntry, checkNoReentry, checkNoRecursion, verifyf, checkf are compiled into the executables
    DO_ENSURE                                       If true, then ensure, ensureAlways, ensureMsgf and ensureAlwaysMsgf are compiled into the executables
    STATS                                           If true, then the stats system is compiled into the executable.
    ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                               If true, then debug files like screen shots and profiles can be saved from the executable.
    NO_LOGGING                                      If true, then no logs or text output will be produced

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#if UE_BUILD_DEBUG
    #ifndef DO_GUARD_SLOW
        #define DO_GUARD_SLOW                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_CHECK
        #define DO_CHECK                                1
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_ENSURE
        #define DO_ENSURE                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef STATS
        #define STATS                                   ((WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS || !WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA || USE_STATS_WITHOUT_ENGINE || USE_MALLOC_PROFILER || FORCE_USE_STATS) && !ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS)
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES
        #define ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                           1
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE
        #define ALLOW_CONSOLE                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef NO_LOGGING
        #define NO_LOGGING                              0
    #endif
#elif UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
    #ifndef DO_GUARD_SLOW
        #define DO_GUARD_SLOW                               0
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_CHECK
        #define DO_CHECK                                1
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_ENSURE
        #define DO_ENSURE                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef STATS
        #define STATS                                   ((WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS || !WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA || USE_STATS_WITHOUT_ENGINE || USE_MALLOC_PROFILER || FORCE_USE_STATS) && !ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS)
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES
        #define ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                           1
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE
        #define ALLOW_CONSOLE                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef NO_LOGGING
        #define NO_LOGGING                              0
    #endif
#elif UE_BUILD_TEST
    #ifndef DO_GUARD_SLOW
        #define DO_GUARD_SLOW                               0
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_CHECK
        #define DO_CHECK                                USE_CHECKS_IN_SHIPPING
    #endif
    #ifndef DO_ENSURE
        #define DO_ENSURE                               USE_ENSURES_IN_SHIPPING
    #endif
    #ifndef STATS
        #define STATS                                   ((USE_MALLOC_PROFILER || FORCE_USE_STATS) && !ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS)
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES
        #define ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                           1
    #endif
    #ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE
        #define ALLOW_CONSOLE                               1
    #endif
    #ifndef NO_LOGGING
        #define NO_LOGGING                              !USE_LOGGING_IN_SHIPPING
    #endif
#elif UE_BUILD_SHIPPING
    #if WITH_EDITOR
        #ifndef DO_GUARD_SLOW
            #define DO_GUARD_SLOW                           0
        #endif
        #ifndef DO_CHECK
            #define DO_CHECK                            1
        #endif
        #ifndef DO_ENSURE
            #define DO_ENSURE                           1
        #endif
        #ifndef STATS
            #define STATS                               1
        #endif
        #ifndef ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES
            #define ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                       1
        #endif
        #ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE
            #define ALLOW_CONSOLE                           0
        #endif
        #ifndef NO_LOGGING
            #define NO_LOGGING                          0
        #endif
    #else
        #ifndef DO_GUARD_SLOW
            #define DO_GUARD_SLOW                           0
        #endif
        #ifndef DO_CHECK
            #define DO_CHECK                            USE_CHECKS_IN_SHIPPING
        #endif
        #ifndef DO_ENSURE
            #define DO_ENSURE                           USE_ENSURES_IN_SHIPPING
        #endif
        #ifndef STATS
            #define STATS                               (FORCE_USE_STATS && !ENABLE_STATNAMEDEVENTS)
        #endif
        #ifndef ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES
            #define ALLOW_DEBUG_FILES                       0
        #endif
        #ifndef ALLOW_CONSOLE
            #define ALLOW_CONSOLE                           ALLOW_CONSOLE_IN_SHIPPING
        #endif
        #ifndef NO_LOGGING
            #define NO_LOGGING                          !USE_LOGGING_IN_SHIPPING
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    #error Exactly one of [UE_BUILD_DEBUG UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT UE_BUILD_TEST UE_BUILD_SHIPPING] should be defined to be 1
#endif


/**
 * This is a global setting which will turn on logging / checks for things which are
 * considered especially bad for consoles.  Some of the checks are probably useful for PCs also.
 *
 * Throughout the code base there are specific things which dramatically affect performance and/or
 * are good indicators that something is wrong with the content.  These have PERF_ISSUE_FINDER in the
 * comment near the define to turn the individual checks on. 
 *
 * e.g. #if defined(PERF_LOG_DYNAMIC_LOAD_OBJECT) || LOOKING_FOR_PERF_ISSUES
 *
 * If one only cares about DLO, then one can enable the PERF_LOG_DYNAMIC_LOAD_OBJECT define.  Or one can
 * globally turn on all PERF_ISSUE_FINDERS :-)
 *
 **/
#ifndef LOOKING_FOR_PERF_ISSUES
    #define LOOKING_FOR_PERF_ISSUES (0 && !(UE_BUILD_SHIPPING))
#endif

/** Enable the use of the network profiler as long as we are not a Shipping or Test build */
#ifndef USE_NETWORK_PROFILER
#define USE_NETWORK_PROFILER !(UE_BUILD_SHIPPING || UE_BUILD_TEST)
#endif

/** Enable UberGraphPersistentFrame feature. It can speed up BP compilation (re-instancing) in editor, but introduce an unnecessary overhead in runtime. */
#define USE_UBER_GRAPH_PERSISTENT_FRAME 1

/** Enable validation of the Uber Graph's persistent frame's layout, this is useful to detect uber graph frame related corruption */
#define VALIDATE_UBER_GRAPH_PERSISTENT_FRAME (!(UE_BUILD_SHIPPING || UE_BUILD_TEST)) && USE_UBER_GRAPH_PERSISTENT_FRAME

/** Enable fast calls for event thunks into an event graph that have no parameters  */
#define UE_BLUEPRINT_EVENTGRAPH_FASTCALLS 1

/** Enable perf counters on dedicated servers */
#define USE_SERVER_PERF_COUNTERS ((UE_SERVER || UE_EDITOR) && WITH_PERFCOUNTERS)

#define USE_CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY_LOAD_DEFERRING 1
#define USE_DEFERRED_DEPENDENCY_CHECK_VERIFICATION_TESTS (USE_CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY_LOAD_DEFERRING && 0)

// 0 (default), set this to 1 to get draw events with "TOGGLEDRAWEVENTS" "r.ShowMaterialDrawEvents" and the "ProfileGPU" command working in test
#ifndef ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_TEST
    #define ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_TEST 0
#endif

#ifndef ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_SHIPPING
    #define ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_SHIPPING 0
#endif

// draw events with "TOGGLEDRAWEVENTS" "r.ShowMaterialDrawEvents" (for ProfileGPU, Pix, Razor, RenderDoc, ...) and the "ProfileGPU" command are normally compiled out for TEST and SHIPPING
#define WITH_PROFILEGPU (!(UE_BUILD_SHIPPING || UE_BUILD_TEST) || (UE_BUILD_TEST && ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_TEST) || (UE_BUILD_SHIPPING && ALLOW_PROFILEGPU_IN_SHIPPING))

#ifndef ALLOW_CHEAT_CVARS_IN_TEST
    #define ALLOW_CHEAT_CVARS_IN_TEST 1
#endif

#define DISABLE_CHEAT_CVARS (UE_BUILD_SHIPPING || (UE_BUILD_TEST && !ALLOW_CHEAT_CVARS_IN_TEST))

// Controls the creation of a thread for detecting hangs (FThreadHeartBeat). This is subject to other criteria, USE_HANG_DETECTION
#ifndef ALLOW_HANG_DETECTION
    #define ALLOW_HANG_DETECTION 1
#endif
#define USE_HANG_DETECTION (ALLOW_HANG_DETECTION && !WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA && !IS_PROGRAM && !UE_BUILD_DEBUG && !ENABLE_PGO_PROFILE)

// Controls the creation of a thread for detecting hitches (FGameThreadHitchHeartBeat). This is subject to other criteria, USE_HITCH_DETECTION
#ifndef ALLOW_HITCH_DETECTION
    #define ALLOW_HITCH_DETECTION 0
#endif

// Adjust a few things with the slack policy and MallocBinned2 to minimize memory usage (at some performance cost)
#ifndef AGGRESSIVE_MEMORY_SAVING
    #define AGGRESSIVE_MEMORY_SAVING 0
#endif

// Controls if UObjects are initialized as soon as they are available or only after the module is "loaded". This only applies to monolithic builds; if there are DLLs, this is how it works anyway and this should not be turned on
#ifndef USE_PER_MODULE_UOBJECT_BOOTSTRAP
    #define USE_PER_MODULE_UOBJECT_BOOTSTRAP 0
#endif

#define USE_HITCH_DETECTION (ALLOW_HITCH_DETECTION && !WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA && !IS_PROGRAM && !UE_BUILD_DEBUG)

// Controls whether shipping builds create backups of the most recent log file.
// All other configurations always create backups.
#ifndef PRESERVE_LOG_BACKUPS_IN_SHIPPING
    #define PRESERVE_LOG_BACKUPS_IN_SHIPPING 1
#endif

#ifndef ENABLE_RHI_VALIDATION
    #define ENABLE_RHI_VALIDATION (UE_BUILD_DEBUG || UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT)
#endif

// Controls whether FPlatformMisc::GetDeviceId() is available to be called.
// When set to 1, calls to this API will be hardcoded to return an empty string
// to avoid running afoul of calling device APIs that platform owners may restrict
// access to without waivers or special steps. Code that uses GetDeviceId() should
// expect to receive empty strings in these cases and response appropriately with
// fallback logic.
#ifndef GET_DEVICE_ID_UNAVAILABLE
    #define GET_DEVICE_ID_UNAVAILABLE 0
#endif
```

When i manually change the option `UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT` to 1 then the first error just gets replaced by all other errorsdefined later. e.g.`In included file: UBT should always define WITH_EDITOR to be 0 or 1`

I suspect the problem is, that i am using the UBT wrong, but i have no idea, how to use it correctly.

For the second error when i look into the header file at the definition of UOpenDoor which is :

```
UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BUILDINGESCAPE_API UOpenDoor : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UOpenDoor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

    //Door Opening Function
    virtual void OpenDoor(float DeltaTime);

    //Door Closing Function
    virtual void CloseDoor(float DeltaTime);

private:
    //Member Variable definition
    FRotator StartingRotation;
    FRotator TargetRotation;

    float DoorLastOpened = 0.f;

    //Exposed parameters
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) 
    float OpenAngle = 90.f;
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float DoorDelay = 2.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) 
    float OpenVelocity = 2.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) 
    float CloseVelocity = 2.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) 
    ATriggerVolume* Trigger;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) 
    AActor* TriggerActor;
};
```

I get the error `Variable has incomplete type 'class BUILDINGESCAPE_API'`
Since i am quite new to c++ i have no idea where to go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this problem has beeen driving me insane for weeks now...

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice [write-up on github](https://gist.github.com/wuyingnan/4730db8eb6df590f9a5ac00f28f0db14) targeted at QtCreator, but it could be abstracted to any tool.

In a nut shell:

1. Generate some intermediate files:

```
cd <project-dir>
make UE4Editor
```

2. Find the needed defines in `Intermediate/Build/Linux/<build-id>/UE4Editor/Development/<project-name>/Definitions.<project-name>.h`
3. Additionally will you need these:

```
#define UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT 1
#define WITH_EDITOR 1
#define WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS 1
#define WITH_PLUGIN_SUPPORT 1
#define IS_MONOLITHIC 1
#define IS_PROGRAM 0
#define UE_EDITOR 1
#define CORE_API
#define COREUOBJECT_API
#define ENGINE_API
#define SLATE_API
#define INPUTCORE_API
#define SLATECORE_API
#define MESSAGING_API
#define RENDERCORE_API
#define RHI_API
#define SHADERCORE_API
#define ASSETREGISTRY_API
#define ENGINEMESSAGES_API
#define ENGINESETTINGS_API
#define SYNTHBENCHMARK_API
#define RENDERER_API
#define GITSOURCECONTROL_API
#define EDITORSTYLE_API
#define SOURCECONTROL_API
#define CHAOS_API
#define PHYSICSCORE_API
#define APPLICATIONCORE_API
#define DEVELOPERSETTINGS_API
```

4. I also need `#define UE_TRACE_ENABLED 0` on UE 4.26

In the linked gist, a Python script was used to parse the `Definitions.<project-name>.h` file and generate an output, that can be used by QtCreator. I have no knowledge of vim+clangd, but with the above information one should be able to find a similar solution.